# Is a private 'property' a 'field'?

Tags: oop, kotlin

Looking into [properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) in Kotlin, this concept is a somewhat new to me so I'm curious, is it legitimate to state that a private `property` is a `field` (instance variable)?

Comment: Aside from the conceptual stuff, yes: a private property behaves like a field and is actually compiled to a field, i.e. no accessor methods.

Comment: @KirillRakhman, only if it has no custom accessors, of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can consider properties as values that you can *get* (and *set* for mutable ones), but they can have custom and overridable behaviour and might not be actually stored. So properties are not fields.

In Kotlin, all member properties, `private` or not, **can have** a [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields), but it is not necessary.

- Property with a backing field:

  ```
  var counter = 0
  ```

  Here, `0` is put into the backing field, and the property *behaves like a field*: getting a value from it returns the value stored in the field, setting a value to it just stores the value into the backing field. But it's not a field, e.g. for Java it will still be a pair of getter and setter.

  <sup>Private properties with no custom accessors [are optimized](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties) and compiled into fields to avoid function call overhead, but it's rather an implementation detail, and adding a custom accessor will also change the bytecode that accessing the property is compiled into.</sup>

  ```
  var counter = 0
      get() = field + 1
      set(value) { if (value >= 0) field = value }
  ```

  Here again the property has a backing field, but its behaviour is different,  custom accessors `get()` and `set(...)` will be executed in statements like `counter = something` or `val x = counter`. This is true for accessing the property both from within and from outside the class, and `private` properties are not different here.

  The backing field can be accessed directly only inside the accessors code by a soft keyword `field`, it is not exposed to the other code. If you want to access the backing value from somewhere else, you have to define another [backing property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties). You can expose a backing field to Java code by adding `@JvmField` annotation to the property (this won't make it accessible from Kotlin).
- Property without a backing field

  When a property has no initializer and has at least `get()`, it is a property with no backing field:

  ```
  val time: Long get() = System.currentTimeMillis()
  ```

  No backing field will be generated for it, but you can use another property as a backing property as stated above.

---

Properties with no backing field can also be [extension properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties), which is quite far from *fields*:

```
val String.isCapitalized: Boolean get() = length > 0 && this[0].isUpperCase()
```

These can also be `private`, but it will have different semantics.

Answer (score 1):

No because "classes in Kotlin cannot have fields" ([Properties and Fields - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)).

In addition, "if you need to expose a Kotlin property as a field in Java, you need to annotate it with the `@JvmField` annotation" ([Calling Kotlin from Java - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html)). It still isn't a field though.

As Kotlin classes do not have fields it is best to always refer to properties as properties.

Comment: A private property, in Java, IS a private field (under certain conditions). The annotation is only needed to *expose* a field (make it more visible than private). "access to private properties with default getters and setters is optimized so that no function call overhead is introduced"